# how to fix return only 0

Tags: mysql, bash

i have this bash script, i want to search everything in the list.txt in mysql

if it is not found I want to write it in a newout.txt file.

everything is written to each other in the list.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/tmp/list.txt"


while IFS= read -r line
do
FIELDVALUE=$(mysql databse -u user-ppw -e "SELECT count(name) FROM db WHERE name LIKE '$line';")
count=$(echo $FIELDVALUE |awk '{print $2}')

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
 echo "greater that 0 "
else
 echo "$line" >> /tmp/newout.txt
fi

done <"$file"
```

I always get back 0 though it is definitely there

:
0
lower than 0
0
lower than 0

Comment: Does this work: `FIELDVALUE=$(mysql database -u user-ppw -e 'SELECT count(name) FROM \`db\` WHERE name REGEXP "'$line'";')`

Comment: Or `FIELDVALUE=$(mysql database -u user-ppw -e 'SELECT count(name) FROM \`db\` WHERE name LIKE "%'$line'%";')`

Comment: I have noticed that it is not the FIELDVALUE varbiale, but he does not correctly put the $ list in context with the FIELDVALUE varibale

Comment: @MikeShiwa : To find the bug, dump the FIELDVALUE and count to stdout; or, run the script using `-x`.

Comment: Put double quotes around FIELDVALUE where it's used on a rhs: `count=$(echo "$FIELDVALUE" |awk '{print $2}')` .